# Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type in Room Android?

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-flow

I am getting the following error when I build my application

```
Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<? extends java.util.List<com.notification.NotificationEntity>>)
```

This is my Entity class

```
@Entity
internal data class NotificationEntity(
@PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "notification_id") val notificationId: String,
val title: String,
val body: String?,
@ColumnInfo(name = "is_actionable") val isActionable: Boolean,
@ColumnInfo(name = "created_at") val createdAt: Instant,
@ColumnInfo(name = "is_read") val isRead: Boolean = false)
```

And this is my Dao Class

```
@Dao
internal interface NotificationDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM NotificationEntity ORDER BY created_at ASC")
suspend fun getAllNotifications(): Flow<List<NotificationEntity>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun saveNotification(notifications: List<NotificationEntity>)
}
```

Can someone help what is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare Dao's function which returns `Flow` the function should not be suspendable. [Please see docs.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observablehttps://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observable)

Change your code to:

```
@Dao
internal interface NotificationDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM NotificationEntity ORDER BY created_at ASC")
fun getAllNotifications(): Flow<List<NotificationEntity>>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
suspend fun saveNotification(notifications: List<NotificationEntity>)
}
```

And add [type converter](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) for `Instant` type which used in NotificationEntity if not yet added.